# how to switch between top components taps programmatically in java swing netbeans platform

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-platform

I want to manage viewing top components taps using code without need to click the tab, I have four top components, three of them are "editor" top component and the last one is explorer top component when I click button in it I want to control which of the three "editor" be viewed (selected) I'm using Netbeans Platform

image top components(package contents,Viewer,Add Metadata and Add Resources)
[image]

this.parent get the top components Parent

```
this.getParent() = (javax.swing.JPanel) javax.swing.JPanel[Content displayer,0,30,1110x720,invalid,
layout=org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol.plaf.StackLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,
border=javax.swing.border.MatteBorder@b3f746,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

Comment: without need to click the tab I have four top components, - CardLayout (maybe instead of StackLayout)

Comment: without real description and code in SSCCE / MCVE form isn't this question answerable

Comment: it is very clere question 
I want to know how to set selected top component tap ,
in the parent container there is not function to do that

Comment: Have you tried `showComponent` method of `StackLayout`?

Comment: Maybe `setSelectedComponent` or `setSelectedIndex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to find Your topcomponent.
You can use this method:

```
WindowManager.getDefault().findTopComponent("YourTopComponentPreferredId")
```

or You can iterate over the opened topcomponents with this method:

```
WindowManager.getDefault().getRegistry().getOpened()
```

and select that You need.
After You have the *TopComponent* call `open()` and `requestActive()` methods on it.